# Styling a button to take up minimum space

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to style a button to take minimum space and set the CSS padding to 0.

But it seems to still take quite a bit of space...any way to get it to take enough space to display the label.

Comment: If you can render the button in a browser which has "developer tools" (e.g Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome - on a PC) then you should be able to get the tools to show you what padding, margins, etc. are being applied to the button and what CSS applies to it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton this is not javascript but nativescript which is mobile developing ;)

Comment: @MarekMaszay Are you saying that only a mobile device can render the page? The latter seems unlikely.

Comment: @AndrewMorton only that in browsers can have different css styles than in android/ios default styles

Comment: @MarekMaszay Ahh, then you might need some sort of [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/).

Answer (score 1):

```
.css-class {    
  height: 5px;
}
```

Setting height worked for me, just add height or width properties to the css class

Comment: this also works for making the SegmentedBar items smaller. Just apply a height to the SegmentedBar root element

Answer (score 0):

maybe style button like this

```
Button {
   width:auto;
   height:auto;
}
```